# Spotbugs XML report does not have instanceHash value when run using Gradle plugin

Tags: findbugs, spotbugs, find-sec-bugs

I have used **FindSecBugs** plugin in **Spotbugs** to do a static security analysis of my code. Some of my projects are built using **gradle** and some are done using **maven**. I have *successfully* tested for maven which gives me an xml report like :

> BugInstance instanceOccurrenceNum="0" instanceHash="f52576b87914efbf135c588c2449648e" cweid="117" rank="15" abbrev="SECCRLFLOG" category="SECURITY" priority="3" type="CRLF_INJECTION_LOGS" instanceOccurrenceMax="0">

It seems working fine. Next I tried to do the same for Gradle. It looks like I'm not getting the InstanceHash attribute. I use that attribute to make sure bugs aren't repeated. I get a report

> BugInstance type="PATH_TRAVERSAL_IN" priority="1" rank="10" abbrev="SECPTI" category="SECURITY">

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.spotbugs"

    dependencies {
        spotbugsPlugins 'com.h3xstream.findsecbugs:findsecbugs-plugin:1.9.0'
      }

    spotbugs {
        toolVersion = '3.1.12'
        sourceSets = [ sourceSets.main ]
        ignoreFailures = true
       reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findsecbugs")
       effort = "max"
       reportLevel = "high"
       includeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/fsb-include.xml")
       excludeFilter = file("$rootProject.projectDir/fsb-exclude.xml")
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Why are some of the attributes missing in my XML report?

Comment: Ref to the issue on the official bug tracker : https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/issues/161

Comment: There hasn't been a solution given! :/ @h3xStream

Comment: Yep I know. It's just in case a fix is made on SpotBugs. People will see the fix there.

Comment: @h3xStream slenderman and keshavk2, it's the same guy dude.

Comment: The ticket is likely to have a response and a fix eventually. People who fall on this page - in the future - will get a response there.